# Eved: why does it refer to both a slave and a servant?

Tags: commentaries, slave-serve-eved-avadim

What's the different between a slave and a servant, and why are both being refered to in the Tenach as 'eved' (both are being used to translate 'eved').

Comment: "What's the different between a slave and a servant" Can you give more explicit definitions to these concepts?

Comment: Political Correctness. People felt uncomfortable translating it as "slave", so they used "servant" instead